# Vue 3 Inject Plugin with Composition API and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a `controller` plugin to be used global in every component, but I can't make it work with Vue 3 + TypeScript + Composition API I get a TypeScript error

**ui/plugins/controllers.ts**

```
import { App } from 'vue'
import { provider, IProvider } from '@/core/presentation/provider'

export default {
  install: (app: App) => {
    const controllers: IProvider = provider()
    app.provide('controllers', controllers)
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { controllers } from './ui'

createApp(App)
  .use(controllers)
  .mount('#app')
```

**@/core/presentation/provider/provider.ts**

```
import { UserController } from '../controllers'
import { IProvider } from './provider.types'

export const provider = (): IProvider => ({
  users: new UserController()
})
```

**ui/views/Component.vue**

```
import { onMounted, ref, inject, defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const controllers = inject('controllers')

    const user = ref()
    const getUser = async () => {
      const result = await controllers.users.getById(1)
      if (result) {
        user.value = result.toJson()
      }
    }

    onMounted(getUser)

    return {
      user,
      getUser
    }
  }
})
```

Here I get a typescript error when I try to use the controller at this line

```
const result = await controllers.users.getById(1)
```

Error:

> ```
> const controllers: unknown
> Object is of type 'unknown'.Vetur(2571)
> ```

If I set the type with my interface like this I get another typescript error

```
import { IProvider } from '@/core'
...
const controllers: IProvider  = inject('controllers')
```

Error:

> ```
> type 'IProvider | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IProvider'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IProvider'.Vetur(2322)
> ```

I can only make it work like this but I think it's weird:

```
const controllers: IProvider | undefined = inject('controllers')
...
const result = await controllers?.users.getById(1)
```

Comment: I think you should  add undefined here `export const provider = (): IProvider | undefined => ({`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I get the exact same error:
```type 'IProvider | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IProvider'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IProvider'.Vetur(2322)```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with post [Type-safe Vue.js Injections](https://logaretm.com/blog/2020-12-23-type-safe-provide-inject/)

> One thing to note is that the **inject** function produces the resolved type in union with `undefined`. This is because there is the possibility that the injection is not resolved. It's up to you how you want to handle it.

So to deal with `undefined` I followed his advice and create an `injectStrict` function. Here is my final code:

**Component.vue**

```
import { IProvider } from '@/core'
import { injectStrict } from '@/ui/utils'
import { onMounted, ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const controllers: IProvider = injectStrict('controllers')
    const user = ref()
    const getUser = async () => {
      const result = await controllers.users.getById(1)
      if (result) {
        user.value = result.toObj()
      }
    }

    onMounted(getUser)

    return {
      user,
      getUser
    }
  }
})
```

**@/utils/injections.ts**

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

function injectStrict<T>(key: string, fallback?: T) {
  const resolved = inject(key, fallback)
  if (!resolved) {
    throw new Error(`Could not resolve ${key}`)
  }

  return resolved
}

export { injectStrict }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the injection is always resolved, you can use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
const controllers: IProvider = inject('controllers')! // <- notice the exclamation mark!
const result = await controllers.users.getById(1)
```